# Overlay an image with a button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently programming an floorplan app where I have to overlay Buttons on a image.

[image]

In native SwiftUI i solved this by using .overlay on the image, measuring the current View size with Geometry Reader and aligning the buttons depending on the size. This gives me a good working responsive design. Now I however have to migrate to Flutter

I tried using a Stack to archive this:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.asset(
      'assets/images/plans/Catalpa.sw.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: .5 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      left: .5 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    ),
  ],
```

The problems is that MediaQuery just gives me the full screen size and my images should not be expanded to the full screen. I also tried using the LayoutBuilder but here again the LayoutBuilder just gives me the maxSize it gets from his parent, which is not working for me because the image is resizable.

```
child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: .274 * constraints.biggest.height,
                  left: .536 * constraints.biggest.width,
                  child: Text('Test'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
```

As I am very new to flutter I do not know a lot of possibilities here. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: could you add simple snippet code which we can run and test your code?

Comment: it all depends on how you show your image (fit width / fit height / cover etc) - but in either case you need to know the image physical size

Comment: But why can't I adjust to fit the width f.e. and then measure the ViewSize that was created to get a height. (I do that in SwiftUI by using overlay and GeometryReader) Then I would just have to offset the button depending on width and height.

Answer (score 0):

try to add Container before the LayoutBuilder, Than you can use MediaQuery in container width

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).